# I can connect with tsql, but bsqldb fails

Tags: linux, t-sql, freetds

I am trying to run a TSQL script using FreeTDS.  I can connect to the server using the tsql command line utility.

> tsql -S serverName -U userName -P password

This gives me a prompt and I can execute TSQL commands.

When I try the same thing with the bsqldb command line utility, all I get is a carriage return and no prompt.  To move along I have to ^C.

> bsqldb -S serverName -U userName -P password

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The tsql command line utility is an interactive tool and when it connects it issues a prompt.

The bsqldb command line tool is not an interactive tool.  When it connects it outputs just a carriage return and starts reading from either standard in or if specified the input file.

The key to solving this dilemma was to [enable logging](http://www.freetds.org/userguide/logging.htm).